# How should I work with MELPA and MELPA-stable using Emacs?

Tags: emacs, repository, melpa

I often run into a problem when I install packages with Emacs: what can I do if one of the packages is broken in **melpa** and the other is broken in **melpa-stable**? For example if I use **melpa-stable** *elscreen* fails on startup:

```
run-hooks: Symbol's function definition is void: elscreen-start
```

but if I run on **melpa** *elscreen* works but *cider-nrepl* fails to start up. I checked their github profile and their build is currently failing. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both `melpa` and `melpa-stable`, and pin certain packages to certain repositories by customizing `package-pin-packages`:

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(setq package-pinned-packages
      '((imenu-anywhere . "melpa-stable")
        (spaceline . "melpa-stable")
        (clj-refactor . "melpa-stable")
        (cider . "melpa-stable")
        (clojure-mode . "melpa-stable")
        (linum-relative . "melpa-stable")
        (aggressive-indent . "melpa-stable")
        (evil-leader . "melpa-stable")
        (evil-visualstart . "melpa-stable")
        (evil-jumper . "melpa-stable")
        (evil-snipe . "melpa-stable")
        (evil . "melpa-stable")
        (evil-commentary . "melpa-stable")))
```